# How to create Virtual Camera on MacOS without CoreMediaIO (because CoreMediaIO is deprecated)

Tags: macos, driver, kernel-extension, virtual-webcam, coremediaio

We can create Virtual Camera for MacOS with [`CoreMediaIO`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CoreMediaIO/Introduction/Intro.html).

We have few Sample Virtual Camera using CoreMediaIO.

- https://github.com/johnboiles/coremediaio-dal-minimal-example
- https://github.com/seanchas116/SimpleDALPlugin
- https://github.com/lvsti/CoreMediaIO-DAL-Example

But CoreMediaIO is deprecated so How we can create Virtual Camera without CoreMediaIO?

Comment: I think what is deprecated is the DAL plugins, instead of the CoreMediaIO entirely. You should still be able to create virtual camera following their post here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremediaio/creating_a_camera_extension_with_core_media_i_o